# Rename view programmatically in SP2010

Tags: view

I have a problem with renaming of view.
I have something like this but it doesn't work.

```
            var list = web.Lists["List name"];
            var oViewCollection = list.Views;
            for(var i = 0; i < oViewCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                if (oViewCollection[i].Title == "Some view"
                {
                    oViewCollection[i].Title = "TEST";
                    oViewCollection[i].Update();

                    list.Update(true);
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Nothing, title didn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

var list = web.Lists["List name"];
var view = list.Views["Some view"];

if(view != null)
{
    view.Title = "Test";
    view.Update();

    list.Update();
}

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Note - This will set the view title. We won't be able to change the view URL since it is a readonly field

Comment: So there is no possibility to change name of the view?

Comment: There is no Name property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview_properties.aspx.. You can always copy an existing view and create a new one with new URL. Then you can delete the old view.